# Font wont change, instead it crashes my app on launch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts

I put a font in the assets folder I created and have implemented the following code in my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
//      Code to change Welcome text to 'BankGothic Bold' font
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BankGothic Bold.ttf");
        TextView myTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WelcomeTextView);
        myTextview.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
//      Code to display Home Fragment on App Launch Page
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                homeFragment,
                homeFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();
    }
```

I have created the ID in the XML file too so that is fine.

If I include this code my app crashes on launch:

```
//      Code to change Welcome text to 'BankGothic Bold' font
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BankGothic Bold.ttf");
        TextView myTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WelcomeTextView);
        myTextview.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

If I remove it my app works fine with the standard font. Does anyone know why?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: change name of font file to something without space and and all in lowercase, then use this name in your code.

Comment: Tried using 'bankgothic.ttf' but sadly didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: can you post the `logcat` error when you run app and it crashes?

Comment: Ah yes,  I didnt think of looking at that. Give me a moment pls

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

Comment: @JohnMilland it looks like myTextview is null

Answer (score 0):

Check whether WelcomeTextView is in activity_main.xml

Do you have WelcomeTextView in another xml layout file?

To change font you should use Calligraphy or create a custom TextView